# Automatically mount partitions on Fedora CoreOS

Tags: fedora, coreos

On Fedora coreOS there is no file /etc/fstab on the default install.

What is the correct place to have partitions automatically mounted on boot?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this thread](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/fstab-file-in-fedora-coreos/20564)

This can be done either by creating an fstab file or by using systemd mount units